# Laravel migration: trying to add foreign key to table but overarching table remains empty

Tags: mysql, laravel, api, foreign-keys, migration

I'm somewhat new to Laravel. I'm currently working on a project which requires me to send sensor data from an ESP32 to a REST API, I'm using Laravel for that API.

I want to make an overarching table for the 3 tables I already have (1 for every sensor), so I also have all my data in 1 table for later outputting it on a front-end.

The catch is that when I add a foreign key to my table, the overarching table remains empty.

I have tried a lot of approaches, but nothing I do seems to work. I get error messages ranging from having no index for the constraint to doing that and getting errors about having more than 1 primary key.

Below are my 2 migrations, I hope someone can help me with my problem. :)

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateOverarchingTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('overarching', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->decimal('decibel');
            $table->foreign('decibel')->references('decibel')->on('microphone');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('overarching', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign('overarching_decibel_foreign');
        });
        Schema::dropIfExists('overarching');
    }
}
```

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateMicrophoneTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('microphone', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->decimal('decibel');
            $table->decimal('timeSpentMs')->default('0');
            $table->date('timestampDate')->nullable();
            $table->time('timestampTime')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('microphone');
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what are you doing to fill the table?

Comment: Hi there! I work out of a controller where it stores the data I need as a new Model in my table. It now works to the point that it fills my microphone table (where my primary key is), but still the overarching table remains empty.

Comment: are you making inserts into this "overarching" table?

Comment: Not into the overarching table specifically. I thought the values would add to the 'overarching' table automatically on migrate and seed

Comment: I now have this in my controller for the table

```public function createMicrophoneReading(Request $request) {
        $microphoneReading = new Microphone;
        $microphoneReading->decibel = $request->decibel;
        $microphoneReading->timeSpentMs = $request->timeSpentMs;
        $microphoneReading->timestampDate = Carbon::today()->toDateTimeString();
        $microphoneReading->timestampTime = Carbon::now()->toTimeString();

        $microphoneReading->save();
        return response()->json([
            "message" => "Microphone record was created"
        ], 201);
    }```

Comment: https://prnt.sc/26ds31c

Comment: no you have to insert records into the table if you want it to have records ... foreign keys are a constraint on a field, they don't populate things

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know! Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Since I only send 1 POST request,  do I insert the data in the same function or make a different function for that? And if so what would the syntax for that be. I can't find it anywhere :/